# Ce₂(SO₄)₃ solubility in water

Tags: equilibrium, solubility, coordination-compounds, crystal-structure

I have mostly come across examples of solids whose solubility increases in liquids with an increase in temperature. However, there seem to be exceptions to generalized rule this such as the solubility of $\ce{Ce2(SO4)3}$ in water. What makes this substance so special?

Comment: No need to go after anything this exotic. There are great many exceptions, to the point that there is hardly any rule at all.

Comment: @IvanNeretin While exceptions are not exactly rare, the general rule (or trend) *is* that solubility of salts increases with temperature. http://www.chemgapedia.de/vsengine/media/vsc/de/ch/11/aac/vorlesung/kap_7/kap7_5/kap7_52/grafik/t_abhaengigkeit.gif Here's another one, CaCrO4 http://docplayer.org/docs-images/80/80977997/images/2-0.jpg And the well know NaCl, whose solubility is nearly temperature independent.

Comment: See for reference, sodium sulfate: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/10457/why-does-sodium-sulfate-have-an-unusual-solubility-temperature-curve?r=SearchResults

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/51862/why-does-the-solubility-of-some-salts-decrease-with-temperature

Comment: It depends on just what part of the phase diagram you are on. Coming up from freezing. Solubility increases. Past the eutectic solubility decreases up to the boiling point if pure water.